# Automation Log in Marketing Cloud location?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

Can somebody tell me where can i find the automation log from automation Studio within the Marketing Cloud? I am unable to find this file, or a resource to direct me to the file.

Answer (score 0):

There's no file. The *activity* can be found in the Activity tab:

[image: activity-tab-automation-studio]